# Replace mat-icon with SVG graphic

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Angular newbie here..could someone direct me to the right way how could I replace the existing Material icons with custom ones properly, more precisely with the SVG graphics? Something like this:

So this:

```
<mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
     {{nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
</mat-icon>
```

With this:

```
<mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
     {{nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'INSERT_SVG_1_HERE' : 'INSERT_SVG_2_HERE'}}
</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfotunatley this does not exactly solve your problem, because you will need to use the argument `svgIcon` on `the mat-icon` element instead of using the `innerText` of `mat-icon` but otherwise it works:

1. You have to allow to angular to import from svg's by declaring the module.
2. To import/inline the icons into javascript, you will have to override the loader. This can be achieved through using the `raw-loader`.
3. Now you will be able to import the svg into angular and register them through the `MatIconRegistry`;

As an example:

```
// src/typings.d.ts

declare module '*.svg' {
  const svg: string;
  export default svg;
}
```

```
// src/app/app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatIconModule, MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

import thumbsUp from '!!raw-loader!./thumbs-up.svg';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule, 
    MatIconModule 
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIconLiteral(
        'thumbsUp', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(thumbsUp));
  }
}
```

```
// src/app/app.component.html
<mat-icon svgIcon="thumbsUp"></mat-icon>
```

```
// src/app/thumbs-up.svg
<svg>...</svg>
```

**Another approach** would be to install `@mdi/svg`

`npm install @mdi/svg`

and then follow the steps above, with the difference to import each necessary icon as well, e.g. `expand_more` and `chevron_right`

so in `src/app/app.module.ts`

```
// src/app/app.module.ts
...
import expandMore from '!!raw-loader!@mdi/svg/svg/chevron-down.svg';
import chevronRight from '!!raw-loader!@mdi/svg/svg/chevron-right.svg';
...
export class WeddingDayModule {
  constructor(
    private iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {
    iconRegistry
      .addSvgIconLiteral('chevron_right', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(chevronRight))
      .addSvgIconLiteral('expand_more', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(expandMore));
  }
 }
```

And in the html just as a simplification... but you will get the idea...

```html
//src/app/app.component.html
...
<mat-icon [svgIcon]="expanded ? 'chevron_right' : 'expand_more'" (click)="expanded = !expanded"></mat-icon>
...
```

the down side with this approach is, that you will have to register all the icons you want to use... But at least you stay in the same domain of change. Instead of using the ligatures you can change them all through the `svgIcon` and you get more icons than just the icons the outdated `material-design-icons` library holds.

I hope that helps

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that approach and I managed to use it as an svgIcon on mat-icon… However I'm trying to find a way to replace 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right' with custom SVG-s, so it could be used in conditionals etc… Don't know if it's possible at all? Thanks for the effort, will award it when it's enabled

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the implementation you want to achieve is to find a consistent way of either using a custom svg icon or a `defaultish` material icon?

Comment: yes correct - so if I have custom let's say US-flag SVG graphic, I would like to be able to use it as 'us_flag_custom' anytime I need it

Comment: Okay, so how about to turn it the other way around and use e.g. `@mdi/svg`, and then import the material icons as mentioned above.
Then they can at least be used consistently as svgIcon's. Not perfect as you would have to register each material icon that you want to use... If you think that would solve the problem, I'll update the answer

Comment: Yes please that approach would be interesting to see as well

Comment: @Smithy btw, just figured, you can mix it without problem. `<mat-icon [svgIcon]="icon">{{ icon }}</mat-icon>`, if no ligature is available, the svgIcon is taken.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **angular-svg-icon**

> The angular-svg-icon is an Angular 7 service and component that
>   provides a means to inline SVG files to allow for them to be easily
>   styled by CSS and code.
>
> The service provides an icon registery that loads and caches a SVG
>   indexed by its url. The component is responsible for displaying the
>   SVG. After getting the svg from the registry it clones the SVGElement
>   and the SVG to the component's inner HTML.

For more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-svg-icon

Answer (score -2):

If it's not part of the material icons, why not use it as a normal image.
Just use it like normal image tag:

```
<img src="{{nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'path_to_svg_file_1.svg' : 'path_to_svg_file_2'}}">
```

Comment: It does not seem to work like that…shows only '../folder' if I insert it like  '../assets/SVG_file.svg'